# Resolve not called in a recursive promise function

Tags: javascript, google-api, promise, synchronization

I've made a recursive function to implement [incremental synchronization of  Google Calendar Events list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync) with their JavaScript API, and everything seems to work except the `resolve()`, and I dont understand why...

What am I missing?

```
  syncEvents (calendarId) {

      let eventsItems = []
      let syncToken = null
      let pageToken = null

      function next(params) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          gapi.client.calendar.events.list( params ).then( (response) => {
            syncToken = response.result.nextSyncToken;
            pageToken = response.result.nextPageToken;

            let items = response.result.items
            eventsItems.push(items)

            if (pageToken) {
              return next({
                'calendarId': params.calendarId,
                'pageToken': pageToken,
                'syncToken': syncToken
              })
            }
            if (syncToken) {
              console.log('ok now resolve!') // <= This is called...
              resolve(response)
            }

          })
        })

      }

      next({'calendarId': calendarId}).then( (result) => {
          console.log(eventsItems) // <= And this is not called...
      })

  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to wrap your next fn in a promise since gapi already returns a promise

Comment: When you do `return next()`, `resolve()` is never called for that promise.  Never.  But there's no need to wrap a promise in another promise.  Get rid of the entire `new Promise()` here and just return `gapi.client.calendar.events.list(...).then()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may attempt you with some new async/await sugar then you don't need any recursive function :)

```
async syncEvents(calendarId) {
  const eventsItems = []
  const query = {calendarId}

  while (true) {
    const response = await gapi.client.calendar.events.list(query)
    const {nextSyncToken, nextPageToken, items} = response.result

    eventsItems.push(items)

    if (nextPageToken) {
      query.pageToken = nextPageToken,
      query.syncToken = nextSyncToken
    } else {
      return eventsItems
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only resolving the deepest promise at the end of your recursion stack.  Resolve never gets called for any promises higher in the stack because the return gets called before the resolve does.